# Checkpoint system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm confronted with a problem with the implementation of checkpoints system. So I following a tutorial and I got a checkpoint system working like that :

1. A gameobject SpawnPoint (nothing special about him)
2. A gameobject Checkpoint with the content here :

   ```
   [SerializeField]
   private Transform SpawnPoint;

   void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
   {
       if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
       {
           SpawnPoint.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
       }
   }
   ```
3. And a gameobject Respawn (when hit him respawn to last checkpoint)

   ```
   [SerializeField]
   private Transform SpawnPoint;

   [SerializeField]
   private GameObject player;

   void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
   {
       if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
       {
           player.transform.position = SpawnPoint.position;
       }
   }
   ```

But now I want to replace the gameobject Respawn, when the player lost a life just respawn the player to the last checkpoint. How can I do that ? I tried to change the script Respawn with just `player.transform.position = SpawnPoint.position;` but It's failed hard...

Thanks per advance ! 
PokeRwOw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a script similar to this in the player gameObject, as long as you can already track the lives he's lost.

```
 //Update checks every frame, instead of only on collision with certain objects.
    void Update ()
    {
      // Equal to or less than is to prevent errors from multiple lost lives in a short amount of time.
      if(lifeVariable =< 0)
      {
         player.transform.position = SpawnPoint.position;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I thinked about it, but i'm using a GameManager script and can't use your solution I think

Comment: I wish you the best of luck, I've never had success with universal management scripts.

Comment: Finally I followed your advice and It's work, thank you ! :)